# How does google-services.json replace default_web_client_id?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

First i'd just like to say I have Google play sign in up and working. However I have struggling to understand how a specific line of code works.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

I would like to know how  requestIdToken is getting my real clientId.
when investigating: default_web_client_id = **0x7f060035**

when i log R.string.default_web_client_id i get: **2131099701**

when I log getString(R.string.default_web_client_id) i get: 
**xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx0tfctc0fa0a.apps.googleusercontent.com(my web client id)**

This id is not located in my strings or resources folder. However it is in my google-services.json file.

My question is how is getString or that default_web_client_id resolving into a clientID in a Json File?

Thanks in advance for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) you apply gradle plugin which then generates new xml file with values from the JSON

Comment: Good info! Thanks so much, wish I would have came across that sooner! Would have saved me some time of mental anguish.